# Hibernate query for multiple associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-criteria

I have the following structure in JAVA.

```
public class Article {
    private long id;
    private Source source;
}

public class Source {
    private long id;
    private Type type;
}

public class Type {
    private long id;
    private String sourceType;
}
```

How do I query all articles with Type.id = somevalue using Hibernate Criteria. Right now I can only query until Source class like this

```
Criteria query = currentSession().createCriteria(Article.class)
            .createAlias("source", "s")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("s.id", Long.parseLong(typeId)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Criteria query = currentSession().createCriteria(Article.class)
        .createAlias("source", "s")
        .createAlias("s.type","t")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("t.id", Long.parseLong(typeId)));
```